# Advice on switching PhDs

Tags: phd

I'm currently a second year PhD student in a field in which I lost interest. It is an interdisciplinary program of my real underlying interests (a subfield of computer science) and biology. Most of the people which I talk to are from biology and the university is at a 2-hour travelling distance from my home.

Near the city I live in is another university from which I graduated. The professor I've had here, let's call him professor A., has written a recommendation letter for me to professor B. of my current PhD program. Professor A. is into the subfield of computer science which I find interesting and as a bonus, the university is closer to the city I live in.

Therefore, my plan is to talk to professor A. and see whether it is possible to become a PhD student under his supervision. What would you do?

1. Would you first talk to professor B.?
2. Would you prepare a project proposal before the meeting with
   professor A.?
3. And if you have the chance, would you finish the first paper
   together with professor B. first or talk to professor A. before you
   have finished the first paper?

Comment: Any chance you can move somewhere closer? That commute is a drag.

Answer (score 1):

Common advice in the workplace is to only quit a job once you have something new lined up. This generalizes to your situation pretty well. If you talk with prof. B, they will hear that you are unmotivated and do not want to continue. There is no real way back from that.

If you talk to prof A. first, you can explore opportunities with them before deciding. Perhaps they can give you an alternative, for example collaboration on research which can motivate you to continue, so you do not have to switch PhD advisors. Or they'll offer to supervise you. Lots of options. At least you'll able to put it in a different perspective and consider possibilities before talking to your advisor.